# According to Hinduism at what time the life begins?

Tags: life, life-span

In my view the life begins at the time of forming zygote inside the mother's womb. My question is that what is the view of Hinduism about "the beginning of a life"?

Comment: This is a good question. The Bhagavata purANa and especially chandogyopanishad address this in detail. I will post an answer later.

Answer (score 4):

**Scientifically:** You are correct.

**By Hinduism:** Its a soul,which is going to change a body like clothes, leaving off the old one and wearing newones.[see this](http://www.eaglespace.com/spirit/gita_reincarnation.php)

> vaasaa.nsi jiirNaani yathaa vihaaya navaani gRRihNaati naro.aparaaNi.
>
> tathaa shariiraaNi vihaaya jiirNaanyanyaani sa.nyaati navaani dehii..
>   B.G. II-22
>
> वासांसि जीर्णानि यथा विहाय नवानि गृह्णाति नरोऽपराणि।
>
> तथा शरीराणि विहाय जीर्णान्यन्यानि संयाति नवानि देही।।

**That is:** The life of your **body** begins when Zygote was formed in mother's womb, but there is no life of your **soul** (and no death either).

Answer (score 1):

*Krishna* says in the *Bhagavad Gita* that the soul is eternal i.e. life neither begins nor ends. Ofcourse, the body if formed again and again as mentioned in *nobalG's* answer.

TEXT 2.12

> na tv evaham jatu nasam na tvam neme janadhipah na caiva na
>   bhavisyamah sarve vayam atah param

SYNONYMS

> na—never; tu—but; eva—certainly; aham—I; jātu—become; na—never;
>   āsam—existed; na—it is not so; tvam—yourself; na—not; ime—all these;
>   janādhipāḥ—kings; na—never; ca—also; eva—certainly; na—not like that;
>   bhaviṣyāmaḥ—shall exist; sarve—all of us; vayam—we; ataḥ
>   param—hereafter.

TRANSLATION

> Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these
>   kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.

http://www.asitis.com/2/12.html

Answer (score 0):

My SatGuru says human life (i.e., in physical form) starts when the sperm fuses with the Ova. However, it is not that simple.The incoming spirit permeates through both the Ova and the sperm even before they fuse.

Answer is taken from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWXgorb7Ia8

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer by adding some quotes from texts etc...? As you're new user,  please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section.

Comment: I would have if I found the text. However, Yogiraj Gurunath is a fully realized Yogi and he knows what he is talking about. My answer answers the question, do let me know what is missing and I shall edit the answer.